# Build Error with TypeScript 3 and Immutable.js 4

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, immutable.js

Given these versions in `package.json`:

```
"typescript": "^3.0.1",
"immutable": "^4.0.0-rc.9"
```

I simply import `setIn` in a file (without even using it):

```
import { setIn } from "immutable"
```

I get this error from Typescript when I build:

```
[at-loader] ./node_modules/immutable/dist/immutable-nonambient.d.ts:2381:30 
  0:0  error  TS2677: A type predicate's type must be assignable to its parameter's type.
```

It seems like there is a library conflict, but I can't figure out what that is. Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: Below is the link mentioning same issue as yours. maybe it will help :)
https://github.com/facebook/immutable-js/issues/1540

Comment: That's TS 2.9, which may or may not make a difference. Thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting this config in `tsconfig.json` solves the build issue:

`"skipLibCheck": true`

Comment: I'm not sure how this is supposed to fix the problem, if you disable the checks for the type libraries you installed, you might as well remove them as (dev) dependencies.
It's probably better to use `// @ts-ignore` to ignore that line alone and keep the checks in the rest of the project.